# MVC 3 Dropdownlistfor linked modalview list for search is always null on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, search

I have a search form with filters. 1 filter is range which is to be a dropdown with numbers. I have a view using a viewmodal with a ienumerable of search range (my db table) and in the controller i populate this and all works as it should... until the form is displayed and the user tries to filter again in which case my model view ienumerable is now null. Why does it lose the values. Do i need to re-popualte this everytime the users  does a new filter... if so can it be done without repeating calls to the database as the values in the dropdown list wont change.

modal view

```
public class SearchResultsViewModel
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public penguin.Models.Job Job { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<Models.Job> SearchResults { get; set; }
    public string SearchButton { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "keywords")]
    public string keywords { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "location")]
    public string location { get; set; }
    public int RangeID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Models.SearchRange> Range { get; set; } 

}
```

controller

```
const int RecordsPerPage = 25;
    public ActionResult Jobs(ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel model)
    {

        // do something with the search value                    
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchButton) || model.Page.HasValue)
        {

            var entities = new Models.DBDataContext();
            var results = entities.Jobs;

            var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 1;
            model.SearchResults = results.ToPagedList(pageIndex, 25);

            //Range = ViewData["Range"] as IEnumerable<Models.SearchRange>; 
        }
        else {
            var Data = Helpers.ModelHelpers.GetDataContext();
            var ranges = (from r in Data.SearchRanges select r);
            model.Range = ranges;
            //Range = ranges;

        }
        //ViewData["Range"] = Range;
        //model.Range = Range;
        return View(model);


    }
```

View

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel           
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Jobs";
}
@section search {
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Jobs", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "searchForm" }))
{ 
    <fieldset>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.keywords)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.keywords)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.location)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.location)

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RangeID, new SelectList(Model.Range, "ID", "Range", 5))
        <input name="SearchButton" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </fieldset>

  }
 }
<h2>
Jobs</h2>
<div id="resultContainer">
my paged results set will go in here with a link to view job details. I then want
it to come back here and not lose anything 
@* html.Action("Results", "Search")*@
@if (Model.SearchResults != null && Model.SearchResults.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var result in Model.SearchResults)
    {
    <hr />
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large;">
                    @Html.Raw(@result.Title.Truncate(50))</div>
                @Html.Raw(@result.summary.Truncate(50))<br />
                </td>
                    </tr>
    </table>

    }

    <hr />        

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.SearchResults, page => Url.Action("Jobs", new RouteValueDictionary() {
                { "Page", page }, 
                { "Job", Model.Job }
                }), PagedListRenderOptions.DefaultPlusFirstAndLast)}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values in the dropdown list won't change (ever) then you should probably be caching them server side and simply reusing the values each time.  You will need to supply the values to the model each time as the data does not persist between successive requests.  There is NO viewstate in MVC to retain the values.  This is, actually, a good thing.

```
private static IEnumerable SearchRange { get; set; }

static SearchController()
{
   SearchRange = new MyDataContext().SearchRanges.AsEnumerable();
}

public ActionResult Jobs(ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel model)
{ 
    model.Range = SearchRange;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Be careful using static collections as they are not thread-safe and you can encounter thread blocking issues that will cause your app to hang if you have multiple people using it.  There are thread-safe collections you can use (System.Collection.Concurrent), or you can use the built-in HTTP Caching mechanisms. I prefer using `HttpRuntime.Cache` since it also works in the context of unit tests, where as `this.HttpContext.Cache` requires an HTTP context (or requires you to mock one up).

Comment: I'd be more concerned if it weren't a readonly collection.  Personally, if the data NEVER changes I'd probably implement it in code, e.g., `enum`, or via configuration rather than getting it from the database.  Using the cache would be an option if it were large, but you'd potentially have to build a refresh mechanism.  If using EF, the `DbSet<T>` class is thread-safe for static instances.

Comment: Thank you for your help. @tvanfosson in your example how does that cache the items server side, it appears to me it gets the search range each time but i may be missing something. I could use an enum as suggested also but i am trying to learn how to do things so at some point i will need a dropdown with items that may change daily etc Thanks